# 403 Error on LEMP server when using Wordpress with jetPack plugin

Tags: wordpress, nginx, jetpack

**I'm running this server on Centos 6.5 64bits**

- Nginx 1.7.6
- Php-fpm :
  PHP 5.6.1 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Oct  3 2014 07:29:26)
  Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
  with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
- MariaDB
- Nginx runs at 8080 port
- Varnish Cache at 80 port

**I'm using Wordpress 4.0 and jetPack plugin (lastest version)**

Here is my problem : 
I can't connect to any service on Publicize page or Add Contact From (on new post page).

After I click connect, I was redirected to http://www.tienganhratde.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=sharing&action=request&service=twitter&kr_nonce=4e2fef354a&nonce=4dadda0619.

And 403 Error Show

**But I can request http://www.tienganhratde.com/wp-admin/options-general.php normally**.

I already tried these solutions but non of them work:

- chown -R nginx:nginx /home/nginx/blog
- CHMOD all files in Wordpress installation folder to 777
- Re-installed jetPack

Nginx Logs file:

```
2014/10/16 11:44:29 [error] 20050#0: *356 access forbidden by rule, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.tienganhratde.com, request: "PURGE /.* HTTP/1.0", host: "www.tienganhratde.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in server side or wordpress or jetPack.
I'm using iTheme Security plugin. And it's cause this problem.

Trying to determine which setting cause this problem

- Suspicious Query Strings
- Non-English Characters
- Long URL Strings

Disable these setting to make jetPack function work (and enable after then)